# Is there a reason why, Tony didn't think of using this in "Avengers: Endgame"?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, spider-man-far-from-home

In *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, we see that Tony Stark

> has left behind an augmented reality security, defense and artificial tactical intelligence system for Peter, called **E.D.I.T.H** (*Even Dead, I'm The Hero*).

And as we see further in the movie, quoting from [here](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/E.D.I.T.H.),

> [**E.D.I.T.H**] allows the user full access to the entire Stark satellite network, which comes with several hundred tactical drones.

Following [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/215484/when-did-this-character-prepare-the-stuff-in-spider-man-far-from-home/215485#215485), it can be assumed that **E.D.I.T.H** was probably

> developed by Stark during the five years time after the snap. The drone network could have been also put in place during the same time as well (*otherwise, when could he?*).

Considering this, is there a reason why, in *Avengers: Endgame* Tony didn't think of using

> the drone network during the final battle at the Avengers HQ against Thanos and his army?

Comment: He might have started implementing the drone fleet as early as just after *Age of Ultron* -- he certainly had the technology at that time.

Answer (score 13):

Tony didn't have the glasses with E.D.I.T.H. on them during the Battle of Earth. You can see that at various times throughout when he doesn't have his helmet on.

[image: Tony in the battle without his helmet showing he isn't wearing the glasses]

This makes sense as he had left them for Peter and would have done so before going on the Time Heist around the same time he made his will video. After that he didn't have time to fetch them again as after coming back from the Time Heist Thanos followed them right through.

However, presumably F.R.I.D.A.Y. in his suit also had access to the same satellite security network. He probably didn't use them as they wouldn't really have been that effective against Thanos and Tony's whole mission in the battle is to defeat Thanos and keep him busy.

> **Tony:** What's he been doing?
>
> **Thor:** Absolutely nothing.
>
> **Steve:** Where are the stones?
>
> **Tony:** Somewhere under all this. All I know is he doesn't have them.
>
> **Steve:** So we keep it that way.
>
> **Thor:** You know it's a trap, right?
>
> **Tony:** Yeah. And I don't much care.
>
> **Thor:** Good. Just as long we are all in agreement.
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

You could argue he could have called them in later when fighting against Thanos' army but at that point they already have a big army themselves and the little benefit the drones would have provided probably weren't worrying about distracting himself calling them in for.

It’s also worth noting that the drones and the E.D.I.T.H. network are Tony’s legacy to protect the world handed directly over to Peter. It’s his suit of armour around the world, first mentioned in *Avengers: Age of Ultron* and he brings it up again in *Avengers: Endgame*.

> **Tony Stark:** Alive and otherwise what we needed was a suit of armor around the world! Remember that? Whether it impacted our precious freedoms or not- that's what we needed!
>
> <sub>*Avengers: Endgame*</sub>

Comment: `He probably didn't use them as they wouldn't really have been that effective against Thanos` ~> Tony definitely didn't build E.D.I.T.H. for Earthly threats. He always talked about defence against aliens.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation It would appear to be that way yes, but the drone is less powerful than himself and he could only just scratch Thanos.

Comment: Ironman being able to only scratch Thanos didn't prevent Avengers from going against Thanos. The point is: You can always try new methods. A big swarm of drones could at least overwhelm him to keep him distracted from Gauntlet, not to mention his army was still vulnerable.

Comment: @UmbrellaCorporation That's the point I'm making though, Tony is focused on Thanos not his army do probably didn't think of calling the drones in. And he's then so pre-occupied with hand to hand fighting Thanos and getting his arse handed to him that he probably didn't think of using the drones in the heat of the battle.